# Where IN clause when column is a XML data type

Tags: sql-server, xml

```
<users>
    <user key="location" value="123" />
</users>
```

How can I do a `WHERE IN (123,456,789)` type query when the value is a XML column?

My query so far is below:

```
select *
from users
where meta.exist('//user[./@key="location" and ./@value="123"]') = 1
```

Comment: I think you just have to write out (@value="123" or @value="456" or @value="789") … did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

There's many ways to do this. Here's the most straightforward.

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @users TABLE (userId INT IDENTITY, meta XML)
INSERT @users(meta) VALUES 
('<users><user key="location" value="000" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="123" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="456" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="789" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="999" /></users>');

-- Solution
SELECT      u.userId, uv.val
FROM        @users AS u
CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES(meta.value('(//user/@value)[1]', 'int'),
                meta.value('(//user/@key)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8)'))
        ) AS uv(val,[key])
 WHERE  uv.val IN (123,456,789) and uv.[key]='location'
```

**Returns:**

```
userId      val
----------- -----------
2           123
3           456
4           789
```

Comment: to restrict it further, could you make sure ``` key="location" ``` ?

Comment: I borrowed your MCVE, thanks. For this and for the solid answer +1 from my side.

Answer (score 2):

As Alan's solutions shows you, one way is to read the whole set and use an external `WHERE` to filter this. This works and can be the best approach. But with large XMLs `.exist()` is much faster, because the shredding is stopped after the first hit.

Alternatively you can try this:

Credits to Alan Burstein for the MCVE

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @users TABLE (userId INT IDENTITY, meta XML)
INSERT @users(meta) VALUES 
('<users><user key="location" value="000" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="123" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="456" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="789" /></users>'),
('<users><user key="location" value="999" /></users>');
```

--I frame the number list with commas

```
DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(100)=',123,456,789,';
```

--A simple `contains()` looking for `,123,` will find the string

```
SELECT *
FROM @users
WHERE meta.exist('/users/user[@key="location" and contains(sql:variable("@SearchFor"),concat(",",@value,","))]')=1;
```

We can use `sql:variable()` to introduce an external variable into the XQuery. (You can do the same with the *"location"* of course...)

If your list of numbers is taken from a table, you might try something along this:

```
DECLARE @SearchFor TABLE(LookUpNumber INT);
INSERT INTO @SearchFor VALUES(123),(456),(789);

SELECT *
FROM @users
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(',',LookUpNumber) FROM @SearchFor FOR XML PATH('')),','))  A(SearchFor)
WHERE meta.exist('/users/user[@key="location" and contains(sql:column("SearchFor"),concat(",",@value,","))]')=1;
```

The `APPLY` will create the concatenated list of values *on-the-fly* and pass it into the XML using `sql:column()`.